# Symfony 4 UndefinedMethodException addFlash

Tags: symfony4

I have a strange error in Symfony 4

files are "inspired" by symfony documentation.

Here is my service file

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

class MessageGenerator
{
    public function getHappyMessage()
    {
        $messages = [
    'You did it! You updated the system! Amazing!',
    'That was one of the coolest updates I\'ve seen all day!',
    'Great work! Keep going!',
];

    $index = array_rand($messages);

    return $messages[$index];
}
}
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Services\MessageGenerator;

class DefaultController
{
private $message;

public function __construct(MessageGenerator $messageGenerator)
{

    $message = $messageGenerator->getHappyMessage();
    $this->addFlash('success',$message);
    // ...
}


public function getMessage(){
    return $this->message;
}

public function index()
{
    return new Response("<p>Hello !</p> ");
}
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error : 
Attempted to call an undefined method named "addFlash" of class "App\Controller\DefaultController".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since `addFlash` is a helper method, you need to extend the `AbstractController` to gain access to it:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
```

See the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-base-controller-classes-services).

Comment: `AbstractController` does not have that method defined.

Comment: Fair enough, but `AbstractController` uses `ControllerTrait` which does define that method, and according to the docs it's the suggested way to get to what the OP needs help with.

Comment: Oh, did not notice that, sorry (and +1) ! SF4 goes away from extending controllers towards controllers-services, I wouldn't recommend it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Now it has moved to the `ControllerTrait`. So simply put

```
use \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait;
```

somewhere after your controller class declaration begin:

```
class DefaultController
{
    use \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait;

    private $message;
...
```